# Excel formula to index and match 1k names against 140k names and return values from 4 adjacent columns to first worksheet with duplicates

Tags: excel

I am putting together a report for my employer and need help. We had 1015 hires in 2023, and 139k applicants to our positions. Many of the applicants will be listed more than once on this report, possibly in both columns, as they applied to multiple opportunities and/or may have been a temp hire prior to converting to a full-time employee. I need to match the names of the hired employees on one tab against the applicants on another tab, and where there are matches, return the values from the 4 columns adjacent to the name in the "Hires" tab. Only the first match needs to needs to have the data returned, but if it's easier to return the data for all of the matched entries, it is fine. I can fix that later. I think the sheer numbers are throwing me off. I know this should be easier than I am making it but I have a deadline in less than 24 hours. I will keep trying to do this, but if anyone can help. I would really appreciate it. I have a sample file I can upload if this lets me do so.

Initially I struggled with filtered cells b/c I was trying to sort the file. I know better than that now. I had to reformat the names and remove extrenous data, but that has been done. I'm simply getting lost in the details. Do I need to match data column by column or can I move all 4 at once?

I'm not sure how to attach this file, but here is a sample of the ss.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple task using the `HLOOKUP` function. Without some details, it is hard to tell, but HR data is sensitive information. Can you create a simplified example that is anonymized?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I'm sorry for a stupid question, but how do I attach a file?

Comment: HIRES EmpNo Hire Date Hire Type Job Title
Aaron Alifen 107801 5/1/2023 R QC Inspector I
Aaron Wenham 107734 4/10/2023 R Production Builder I
Aarti P. Amin 108570 11/13/2023 R Customer Order Spec I
Abigail Cendejas 108216 8/14/2023 R Facilities Admin Spt I
Adam H. Canale 108466 10/13/2023 R Vascular Territory Mgr
Adam J. Swenson 107860 5/15/2023 R Vascular Territory Mgr
Adetola Famakinwa 107602 2/6/2023 R Clin Research Assoc II

Comment: The info above does not use real people. I have a spreadsheet with several tabs. The first is the master applicant file. It has 30 columns and 140k lines with applicants on them. Many are repetitive. The file with the employee data is on the second tab and includes employee no, date of hire, hire type, and job title, next to the hired person's name.

Comment: The info above does not use real people. I have a spreadsheet with several tabs. The first is the master applicant file. It has 30 columns and 140k lines with applicants on them. Many are repetitive. The file with the employee data is on the second tab and includes employee no, date of hire, hire type, and job title, next to the hired person's name. The order of columns is the same on both sheets, and both sheets have duplicates for various reasons. The emp number will not change. If there is name with multiple listings, the values from the columns mentioned above can be returned to all.

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 or Excel for the web you can apply this formula. If i correctly understand in the Master applicant file the data for an applicant who applied several times is repeated. E.g. in the example Aarti applied 3 times and for all the 3 applications the same data is entered in the columns EmpNo Hire Date Hire Type Job Title for Aarti (rows 5, 8 and 19 and columns A to D in the screenshot).

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",K3:K12,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,XLOOKUP(y,E3:E20,A3:D20)))),1)
```

[image: Hires applicants]

If you work with an older version of Excel you can apply this formula which is in cell G3 and filled across range G3:K12 in the example.

```
=INDEX(A$3:A$20,MATCH($K3,$E$3:$E$20,0))
```

[image: hires index match]

Both formulas can be adjusted to work across two sheets and the ranges of the formulas can be adjusted as required as well. For illustration i've made an example within one worksheet with two small sample tables.